# facetime issues on the phne purchase from uae

Tags: ios, facetime

i have purchased this Iphone from uae and now I am in India inserted an Indian sim card changed my regions to India still cant find Facetime on my phone

Answer (score 1):

Reason: There's [restriction](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5554230) for Facetime in middle eastern countries.
Solution: You need to jail break your phone and install a cydia tweak called  [MEFacetimeiOS8](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5554230)